# Drupal css causing multiple div's next to each other to have image wrapping

Tags: css, drupal-7

I have a page which I am quite happy with the layout of the design: http://dev.twoggle.com/

Then I put this into a Drupal theme and it inserted some extra div's inbetween and I am struggling to figure out how to get my original look back! : dev2.parkingmadeeasy.com.au

the ser_text_right class, when I hover over it using Firebug's page element inspect tool, seems to be overlapping with ser_image_left class - I'm not sure why this is happening.

Below is the css which is causing my problems (when combined with Drupal's output that is).

I'd like to move the entire ser_text_right class upwards, but not sure how?

Many thanks for any help,
Gvanto

```
    /*
=======================================================================
        services-prov
=======================================================================
*/
.services-pro {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #A2A1A1;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
    width:998px;
}
.services-pro .ser {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 47%;
}

.services-pro .ser img {
    margin: 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.services-pro .ser .ser_image_left {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}

.services-pro .ser .ser_text_right {
    padding:0;
}

.services-pro .ser .ser_text_right h4 {
    padding: 3px 0 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}

.services-pro .ser .ser_text_right p {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#block-views-home-slideshow-block { width: 400px; float:right; }
```

Of course you can change the width to whatever width your images are.